# Using sha1 salted password in login form using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sha1

I am using the following to sha1 and slat the user password and save them in the database.

```
$salt = sha1($password);
$hashedPass = sha1($salt.$password);
```

Now I need to be able to use this saved password in the login form.

I am using the following code and the login form keeps telling me wrong information entered:

```
$password = (!empty($_POST['password'])) ? sha1($_POST['password']) : '';
```

could someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](http://php.net/password), instead of manually hashing passwords.

Comment: You are comparing the hashed password with the *salted and* hashed password in your storage. But really you should not use `sha1` for hashnig passwords. Use the password functions provided in php.

Comment: php.net/password is nice, but it requires PHP 5.5+

Comment: @PeeHaa, I don't see why I shouldn't use `sha1` for hashing passwords! in my case if I simply get rid of the `$salt` and just use the `sha1`, the login form works fine. its just the `$salt` that stops it from working properly.

Comment: @MichaelButler, unfortunately my PHP is 5.3

Comment: That's why we have https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat @MichaelButler

Comment: @user3454730 because using sha1 for password hashing is irresponsible and wrong.

Comment: For more info why using sha1 for hashing passwords is horrible http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/10/password-hashing-in-php-talk.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're storing the hashed password in the database as sha1($salt.$password), but in your logic to check the password, you're setting it to just sha1($password). Therefore it would not match the database value.

You would need to set `$password = sha1(sha1($_POST['password']).$_POST['password']);`

However, it doesn't make sense to store the salt as just the sha1 of the password.

Comment: This worked. excellent. but why doesn't it make sense to store the salt as just sha1 ? also, I am not just storing the salt as sha1. I am converting the `$password` to `sha1` and then add the `$password` to `$salt` and then `sha1` both of them. or am I barking at a wrong tree?

Comment: I suppose I should rephrase. According to Wikipedia, a salt is a randomly generated string *for each password* used as additional input to a one-way function (e.g. sha1). In other words, if two users have the same password "test123", the salt should ideally be randomly generated for each of them. if you use Sha1 to generate salt you will get the same result for "test123". Instead, generate a few random characters.   *Disclaimer:* I agree that you should try to use a library to handle this stuff, it will save headaches later.